# I need .slideToggle to work on hover (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, hover, toggle, slide

I've got a navigation div that toggles open on click. My client wants the link that opens the div to link to a page, and toggle the div on hover instead (so the link can lead to another page on click).

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#drawer").hide();
   $(".toggle-drawer").show();

   $('.toggle-drawer').click(function(){
      $("#drawer").slideToggle();
   });  
});
</script>
```

Here's the link to the site: http://gearthirty.com (click the "supersite" link to see what I'm talking about).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're posting on a **question** and answer site, got to the end of your post without including a single **question mark**, and thought you were ready to post it? Guess again.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
$(function(){ // DOM ready shorthand

  var $drawer = $("#drawer"); // Cache your elements
  var $togg   = $(".toggle-drawer");

  $drawer.hide();
  $togg.show();

  $togg.hover(function(){
     $drawer.stop().slideToggle();
  }); 

});
</script>
```